# Google analytics destination url for conversion

Tags: google-analytics

I set a goal as a contact page for Google Analytics but so its not pulling any date in

for example, the contact page is
wordpress/index.php/contact/

the thank you page is

wordpress/index.php/contact-thank-page/

when I enter the goal destination as

/contact-thank-page/

it is not pulling in the goal when I test it.

Any reason why?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your setup? Maybe you have choosen "equals to" instead of "regluar expression"

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 24h before the data shows in the Google Analytics Conversions Report.
Have you checked in the Real-Time Report -> Conversions directly after visiting the /contact-thank-page/? Or maybe you've filtered out your own IP?